# Perl- What function am I looking for? Assigning multiple rules to a specified outcome

Tags: arrays, linux, perl

I've conceptualized a function in my head,and I imagine it exists, but if it does, I don't know the name of it, and for that reason it's difficult to google.

Lets say I want to define two outcomes- I'll call them `Pass` and `Fail`

I want several different rules to apply to each of the two outcomes.

So, for clarity (hopefully), let's say imagine I have a file with different years stored on each line, or blank spaces.

File

```
line1    1978
line2    1989
line3    
line4    1978
line5    1999
line6    
line7    1768
```

Now lets say there is a user input of `1978` to compare to the file.

This date will be compared to each line in the file.

There can only be two results base on the comparison- they are `Pass` and `Fail`.

For a comparison to be in the `Pass` group it would need to meet the following criteria:

```
1) It matches the year in the file
2) Neither the input, or the line in the file contains a year
3) Only one line contains a year, and the other is blank
```

For a line to meet the `Fail` condition:

```
1) Both the input and the file record contain a year, but they are different.
```

So for my example input of `1978` the results would look like this

```
line1    1978   Pass
line2    1989   Fail
line3           Pass
line4    1978   Pass
line5    1999   Fail 
line6           Pass
line7    1768   Fail
```

So basically I want to assign different (and multiple) condition to `Pass` and `Fail` as outlined above.

What I want to know is, what (if anything) is the name of this type of function.

What is the name of some sort of function where I can apply these rules to `Pass` and `Fail`. As far as I'm aware, I can't create `Pass` and `Fail` variables because there is multiple rules for each condition. Is there some other built in function I can use?

Comment: This isn't very clear. Some sample data would help.

Comment: I've updated the question, hope that its clearer now.

Comment: What does "is blank" mean  to you? Will the data be undefined? Will it be an empty string? Will it consist of whitespace?

Comment: The file will have some blank lines where there is no date, so however that would be defined? I'm not sure whether that would be considered an empty string or undefined?

Comment: @bms9nmh It depends on how you parse the file. There are many different ways of parsing files, of parsing delimited or fixed-width fields, and so whether a variable that is intended to represent a single field from a single line of the input file can become `undef` or *a sequence of spaces* or *a single space* or *the empty string* or something else entirely depends on what the parsing code spits out. Neither your question nor the answers that have been given so far focus on parsing files, because the question is focused on the comparison logic. How to parse is a different question entirely.

Comment: Were you looking for a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)? There are very nice CPAN modules for that like [`FSA::Rules`](https://metacpan.org/pod/FSA::Rules)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you. It simply tests each line for the failure condition. Everything else is a pass.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $input = 1978;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {

    $line =~ s/\s*\z//;

    my $result = $line && $input && $line ne $input ? 'Fail' : 'Pass';

    printf "%4s %s\n", $line, $result;
}


__DATA__
1978
1989

1978
1999

1768
```

#### output

```
1978 Pass
1989 Fail
     Pass
1978 Pass
1999 Fail
     Pass
1768 Fail
```

Comment: ok, thats good because the result is stored in a variable which i'm happy about because I want to use the result in an if statement later in something I have planned. Could you just explain to me how the line  my $result = $line && $input && $line ne $input ? 'Fail' : 'Pass';  works?   At the moment I can't see how it is calculating the Pass Fail, although I can see its working.

Comment: Perl's [*conditional operator* `?:`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator) works just like an `if .. then .. else` construct, except that it is usually used to choose one or other of two values depending on a condition. An empty string is *false* in Perl, so `$line && $input` is *true* if both variables contain some characters. Then `$line ne $input` is *true* if the strings are unequal, so the result is an encoding of your criterion ***Both the input and the file record contain a year, but they are different***

Comment: You need to be careful of any whitespace in the file or input data, as a string containing just a space or a newline is *true* and this expression will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Why does line 5 match? The input is 1978 and the file contains 1999? [Ah, you've just edited your question to fix that]

With the proviso that my code returns false for that match (which seems correct to me). Here's my version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @years = (1978, 1989, undef, 1978, 1999, undef, 1768);
my $year = 1978;

say compare($year, \@years);

sub compare {
  my ($year, $years) = @_;
  my @return;

  foreach (@$years) {
    push @return, 1 and next if ! defined $_;
    push @return, 1 and next if $_ == $year;
    push @return, 0;
  }

  return @return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard library function or name for exactly what you've described. You have two arrays and you want to compare their elements using complex criteria. There are an infinite number of ways two arrays could be compared using complex criteria; we can't create a snappy name and write a standard library function for all of them!

Using the minimal assumptions, we can write this function as follows:

```
sub compareArrayElementsForEitherBlankSpaceOrMatch {
    ## takes two array references to compare; assumes they're the same length
    my ($A,$B) = @_;
    my @res;
    if (@$A > 0) {
        $#res = @$A-1; ## preallocate array
        for (my $i = 0; $i < @$A; ++$i) {
            $res[$i] = $A->[$i] eq ' ' || $B->[$i] eq ' ' || $A->[$i] eq $B->[$i] ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
    return @res;
}
```

Demo:

```
my @res = compareArrayElementsForEitherBlankSpaceOrMatch(
    [' ', ' ' , 2000, 2000, 2000 ],
    [' ', 2000, ' ' , 2000, 1900 ]
);
print("@res\n");'
## 1 1 1 1 0
```

---

**Update:** Based on your edit, you're not comparing two arrays against each other, but rather you are comparing one array against a single value. This can be accomplished as follows:

```
sub compareArrayElementsForEitherBlankSpaceOrMatch {
    ## takes an array reference and compares its elements with a given value
    ## an element is considered to match if it is blank or equal to the value
    my ($A,$x) = @_;
    my @res;
    if (@$A > 0) {
        $#res = @$A-1; ## preallocate array
        for (my $i = 0; $i < @$A; ++$i) {
            $res[$i] = $A->[$i] =~ m(^\s*$) || $A->[$i] eq $x ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
    return @res;
}
```

Demo:

```
my @res = compareArrayElementsForEitherBlankSpaceOrMatch(
    [1978,1989,"",1978,1999,"",1768],
    1978
);
print("@res\n");
## 1 0 1 1 0 1 0
```

Note that the line 5 result should be a fail, since 1999 does not equal 1978.

I enhanced the blank check to use a regex test against `m(^\s*$)` rather than a fixed equality check against a single space.

My original comment is still correct regarding the non-existence of a standard function or name for this exact operation.

Comment: sorry I just edited my question prob not long after you posted to make it clearer. Hope this doesn't confuse matters!.